# Want to find the table in excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

I want to find the table in excel and assign it into an array.

[image]

Consider above excel image an example, First few rows have empty and/or middle rows contains some unwanted metadata or vice versa.

I want to only select the table below from Roll No, Name, etc.) to end of the table and assign it into an array temp = [].

How can it be achieved?

Also sometimes, there won't be any empty row cells, then how can we get the table Is there anyway we can use "Roll No" to identify the table?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLhiZ.png)

Comment: But Program also have to find the how many row it need skip. It has to be automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to select always the cell group at the bottom, filled with data, you can navigate to the concerning range.

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(path)
ws = wb.sheets[0]

ws.used_range[-1:,:].end("up").expand().select()  # Selects the range.
range_data = ws.used_range[-1:,:].end("up").expand().value # Stores the range as list of lists.
```

You could also store the data as a pandas dataframe, which might be a more common use case:

```
df = ws.used_range[-1:,:].end("up").expand().options(pd.DataFrame()).value
```

Comment: Thank so much Mouwsy, It is working but when coping to pandas df, I am getting below error.

I tried to check to resolve it, but not getting proper answer.

    return conversion.read(self, None, self._options)
  File "C:\Users\p.a.manimaran\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\__init__.py", line 75, in read
    pipeline = accessors.get(convert, convert).reader(options)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'

Comment: And also, the above program, working based on the empty row cells between table. But sometimes, there won't be any empty row cells, then how can we get the table
Is there anyway we can use "Roll No" to identify the table?